# multi position column with acts_as_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, acts-as-list

How to use multi position columns with acts_as_list gem ?

for sample :

```
rails g migration AddPositionToTodoList position:integer position2:integer position3:integer
```

controller:

```
todo_list = TodoList.find(...)    
todo_list.position1.move_to_bottom
todo_list.position2.move_to_bottom
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, what do you mean by _position_?

Comment: i need three column for sort one model !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible due to the way that internal variables and methods are named.

If you want to work on the `acts_as_list` code to see if you can make this a possibility you're more than welcome. We're happy to receive pull requests :)

Also, it looks like you might benefit from normalising your data structure a bit. Is it possible to have a parent model with three descendant models each with their own position?

Comment: sure :) i commit but not now( because i'm in deadline =)))) ) and i searching best way ! can you give me twitter account ?

Comment: If you're in a hurry, then your best bet is to split up that model into three bits. Multiple orderable attributes points to that as a good case. What are the 'positions' related to? I may be able to help if you let me know that.

Comment: imagine i have four posts to order and admin can change the position of the posts, for example changing the position of post number 1 with post number 2 on a page that show all posts. but there are some pages that showed my posts and i want to let the admin order posts of them separately. for example in page num1 my posts show like 1,3,2,4 and in page num2 my post show like 3,2,1,4 (by admin choice) . so how can i use multiple columns for positioning the posts in my view pages.

Comment: `acts_as_list` allows you to specify the position column in the database. You'll have `x` number of position columns, and `x` number of `acts_as_list` declarations with their different position column references. https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list#more-options Give that a go and see how you get on. There may still be conflicts.

Comment: can you build a sample like my example ( todo_list = TodoList.find(...)    
todo_list.position1.move_to_bottom ) ?

Comment: No, I'd say those helpers wouldn't work as they're not constrained to the attribute. In Rails the position attribute is just an `Integer` object so couldn't respond to those methods. I think what you're wanting is basically outside the scope of `acts_as_list` as it currently stands and more development would be needed to achieve your requirement. As I mentioned, we're very responsive to pull requests and will look to merge your changes provided they're good quality and don't break the existing API.